# Arduino - Converting byte array to string/char array

Tags: android, utf-8, arduino, hid

I'm currently working on communication between devices using HID over a usb cable. I am sending a string that is UTF-8 encoded from an Android device, and would like to receive and read it on my Arduino Leonardo.

My problem is that I am unable to get the received message into any other type. I need to do a human readable string comparison as I'm sending a variety of commands to the Arduino. The IDE either has a type mismatch problem regardless of how I try to convert the received message. I've tried many different things but I will post one as an example. I'm sure there is something I missing that's keeping me from getting this!

```
  int n;
  n = RawHID.recv(buffer, 0); // 0 timeout = do not wait

  if (msUntilNextSend > 2000) {
      msUntilNextSend = msUntilNextSend - 2000;

//      String mystr = "";
//      byte charbuff[10];
//      
//      for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
//      {
//           mystr.concat((char) buffer[i]);
//      }
//      
//      mystr.toCharArray(charbuff, 10);

  char readin[64] = { ' ' };
  readin = (char *)buffer;
  String myString = String((char *)buffer);


  if (strcmp(readin, "test") == 0)
  {
      String resp = "response";
      resp.getBytes(buffer, 64);
      n = RawHID.send(buffer, 100);
  }
```

I've included some comments with bits of a different approach but as I mentioned, I have been unsuccessful in my attempts. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Have you check the endianness ? Can you try with few char and display it as haxa ?

Comment: @Ôrel I'm fairly certain my Android device is Little En., and the Arduino I'm using is Little as well. I don't know the best way to establish an Arduino to Arduino IDE test link, the Serial Monitor doesn't handle HID communication(At least I haven't been able to get it to work). I'll see if I can get a readout of my message in Hex and go from there though.